# Ionic native app rate not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, ionic-native

I tried to show app rating screen in the android platform in ionic. Not working Ionic Native plugins.

```
import { ViewController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AppRate } from '@ionic-native/app-rate';        

export class Popover {

    constructor(
        private appRate: AppRate,
        public platform: Platform) { }

        rate() {
            this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.appRate.preferences = {
                usesUntilPrompt: 2,
                storeAppURL: {
                    ios: 'id12233',
                    android: 'market://details?id=<com.sample.activity>',
                }
            };
            this.appRate.promptForRating(true);
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: where exactly have you called `rate()`?

Comment: i called the popover menu in the root page screen using ngClick

Comment: Are you trying in device or browser? Always check the plugins in device

Comment: always trying in device but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if your install app rate plugin and try the below link
[enter link description here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-rate/)

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-apprate
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/app-rate
```